# VBA: How to change default selection on a Userform & restrict user from texting values under a dropdown column

Tags: vba, excel

I created a userform with a textbox and dropdown options,

1. Textbox  (User)
2. Dropdown (Place)
3. Dropdown (Language)

I am facing 2 issues here,

Issue 1. When I open the the userform the default selection will be under the 2nd option (Place). How I can get the default selection on the 1st option which is a Textbox (User). So that user can give there value and go down and select values from drop down.

Issue 2. User able to type values under the drop down option, how to prevent them from doing so.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cPlace As Range
    Dim cLanguage As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws As Worksheets

    With Me.cboPlace
        .AddItem "Eng"
        .AddItem "Aus"
        .AddItem "USA"
    End With

    With Me.cboLanguage
        .AddItem "English"
        .AddItem "Spanish"
        .AddItem "French"
    End With
    Me.cboLanguage.Setfocus

End Sub
```

Comment: (There's a typo in the title.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TABINDEX is not working, better you rearrange the order of text boxes if they are less in number

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly then

the default cursor position on opening a form is the control whose TABINDEX property is the lowest (usually 1).

To prevent a user from entering free text into a combo or list box set the property MATCHREQUIRED to True

Comment: Thanks @Harassed, MATCHREQUIRED works perfetctly but not the TABINDEX I tried changing it from 0 1 and 3 but still when I open the userform the curser keep coming on '2. Dropdown (Place)'. Do I have to make any other changes